# Power gone along back wall of my house and did not flip breaker

Tags: electrical

I've lost power to all the plugs starting from my oldest daughter and all along the back wall of the house and to the kitchen light switch. But breaker did not flip, but I flipped them all anyway to make sure and still nothing. It did come back on for about 5secs but shut off again. And nothing since. I've run extension cords to various appliances so they still work. But I can't really afford to call and electrician. Please help

Comment: Unplug absolutely everything, then restart and plug back in one by one till the villain does it again. We had this, we even had en electrician in and searched the whole ground floor till we found an unused device plugged in at the back of the conservatory which had shorted out.

Comment: This sounds like a connection gone bad...

Comment: I did still nothing. First plug still shows 120, next 3 plugs show only 2. Fourth plug works fine I'm guessing its on a different line and the the light switch to kitchen doesn't work.

Comment: Ok I just checked the first plug again. Top doesn't work but bottom works fine. Would that throw the rest if the line out?

Answer (score 2):

Since part of the first outlet works it is probably daisy chained to the others. With the power off remove this outlet and look for broken or loose connections. Since 1/2 of the outlet is working one of the metal tabs on the side of the outlet may have failed check this outlet first. a loose connection in a back stab or broken wire is very common for this type of failure. Depending on where the feed to the outlet is landed the bottom could work or the top if one of the tabs broke or failed under load (rare but with these symptoms probable).